# the output of cv::imwrite vs cv::imencode

Tags: c++, opencv, jpeg

Does cv::imencode have an identical behavior to cv::imwrite when converting cv::Mat to JPEG? I know that first one write to buffer and the second write to file but I am asking about the written content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when you call `cv::imwrite()` it did not call `cv::imencode()` internally! both functions uses internal `ImageEncoder`. take a look at [loadsave.cpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp)

Comment: Yes you are right... I have just tried a small code for comparison and it gave back the exact same ByteArray. Thanks!